# SFML VideoMode breaks application

Tags: c++, sfml

Using SFML sf::VideoMode breaks my application, saying that "Singularity.exe has stopped working"

Specifically this line :

```
    _mainWindow.create(sf::VideoMode(1024,768,32), "Singularity");
```

This line is what is causing the problem. When I remove it, the application works fine. Here is the whole code of the main class file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Game.h"

void Game::Start(void)
{
    if (_gameState != Uninitialized)
        return;

    _mainWindow.create(sf::VideoMode(1024,768,32), "Singularity");
    _gameState = Game::Playing;

    while (!IsExiting())
    {
        GameLoop();
    }

    _mainWindow.close();
}

bool Game::IsExiting()
{
    if (_gameState == Game::Exiting)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void Game::GameLoop()
{
    sf::Event currentEvent;
    while (_mainWindow.pollEvent(currentEvent))
    {

        switch (_gameState)
        {
        case Game::Playing:
        {
            _mainWindow.clear(sf::Color(255, 0, 0));
            _mainWindow.display();

            if (currentEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                _gameState = Game::Exiting;
            }
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}


Game::GameState Game::_gameState = Uninitialized;
sf::RenderWindow Game::_mainWindow;
```

Does anyone have any idea of what might be causing this or how to fix it? I am completely new to SFML, so I'm at a loss for what to do.
Thanks, Zuve

Comment: Make a minimal compilable example that shows the error. Just because the application works if you leave out a line does not mean that line is the problem. What does the debugger say where and why it crashes?

Comment: In my opinion it's good to create one, local instance of `sf::RenderWindow` using its constructor in `main` (or other init function) and pass pointer to other functions that need it, like `Game::GameLoop`. Also, try running `sf::VideoMode` without third parameter, leave just resolution and see if that helps.